# Browserify: accessing dom elements from script?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, browserify

I have a javascript library that is meant to be used in client sites as follows:

```
  <script src="foo.js"></script>
  <div id="mydiv"></div>
  <script>
    (function() {
        foo(document.getElementById("mydiv");
    })();
  </script>
```

I.e. foo.js exports a function ("foo") that is suppose to get a DOM element as a parameter.

I want to split foo.js into several different "modules" (logical parts) and I am having a look at [Broserify](http://browserify.org/) or [requireJS](http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html) for that.
The problem is that if browserify (and as far as I have seen, requireJS) don't export any of foo's top level function, so I can't access the "foo" function from the html file as shown above.
It seems that with browserify I can use the *-r* option when building the final js:

```
browserify -r ./foo.js > bundle.js
```

This creates a global *require* that can be use in the client site. I'm not very happy with this solution though, because it is polluting the global space and my script is meant to be embedded in other sites (that may have a clashing *require*).
Am I out of luck here? am I missing something?
I suppose that all I need is a way to join different js source files for easier development and import only one final javascript. Is there any better solution that fits my needs?

M;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you split your script into multiple files then those files need to be able to communicate with each other.  The only way for two different script files to communicate with each other is via the global namespace which is the only thing they have in common.

I'm not familiar with Broserify but in the case of requirejs the way the scripts leverage the global namespace to communicate is that they each pass a reference to themselves into a global "require" or global "define" function when they execute.  requirejs itself then keeps track of the scripts internally so they don't have to make any *other* impact on the global namespace - but requirejs already did by creating the names "require" and "define".

In any case your script can always impact the global namespace by assigning to an undeclared variable which will create a property in the global object:

```
foo = function() {}; // creates global name as long as no other 'foo' is in scope
// or
window.foo = function() {}; // as long as no other 'window' variable is in scope
```

You can always do this no matter how your script is loaded.  Other scripts can now interact via the global name 'foo' by reading and/or assigning properties on this global name.

```
foo.prop1 = 'val1';
if(foo.preExistingProp) {
    // do something
}
```

The main purpose of a library like requirejs is that as you are developing your scripts the relative dependencies might change.  You can imagine script A requiring scripts B and C, and script B requires script D.  Now there multiple orders that the scripts can validly load in.  A few are:

```
D -> B -> C -> A
C -> D -> B -> A
D -> C -> B -> A
```

requirejs takes a dependency *tree* and transforms it into a linear load order on the fly.  As this tree changes it recomputes the load order to ensure it remains valid.

If you need this kind of functionality I encourage you to use such a library though your concern for the global name-space is appropriate.  If you just need a simple linear load order that you will manage yourself then you can have your scripts interact directly with a global 'foo' name as I outlined above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This confirms my feelings. I've found SMASH ([https://github.com/mbostock/smash]) to be more appropriate for my needs, since I don't have to change the way my code is written (see the "wiki" link for a rationale on the module).